# c++ fixed-length data structure that sorts objects according to a specific rule

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need a data structure that contains n-dimentional vectors

This data structure stores only the 100 best of these objects, according to the calculation of a function that takes an n-dimensional vector as input. Objects with a minimum function value are stored.

If I try to put an object in this data structure, it will either not be put if the function value is greater than the top 100 function values(I think there is enough comparison with the last object) or it will be put and will replace last object, if it's function value > than function value of new object. And data structure after that will be sorted.

Is there a data structure in c ++ so that you don’t have to implement it yourself?

Comment: Please read stackOverflow how to ask a question section

Comment: what exactly is wrong?

Comment: You should post what you’ve tried (your code) and be more clear about what you really want

Comment: I need to keep 100 best elements according to specific rule

Comment: I don't have code yet

Comment: Then try and come back to us if you can’t find out

Comment: I can implement this by hand. But I think there is already a solution and I don’t have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Well, no, there is not a data structure in the C++ standard library that will do this.   But, if you define criteria, it will be possible to create your own class type that uses a standard container and (possibly) standard algorithms to achieve what you seek.

Comment: Well i’m not sure there is but i’m not a cpp pro... be sure that if it exists you’ll find things about it and if it doesn’t then the wheel hasn’t yet been invented

Comment: My teacher said that there is such a structure. He didn’t say which one. He said to search. Well, I decided not to search, but to ask here. I don't no, maybe it's something like fixed priority queue...

Comment: @mike Fixed priority queue sounds like a good idea. Think about what happens if you add a new element that is a) better, b) worse or c) equal to the "largest" object in the queue, and how you map better and worse to "being larger".

Comment: It also depends on what you're planning to do with the 100 objects that are stored. If you want to operate on a certain one of them then set should suffice otherwise priority queue is your best option.